# Setting up a router as access point on exisiting Wi-Fi

Tags: encryption, wireless-networking, router

I rent out a room in a large house with Wi-Fi provided. However, Wi-Fi is shared by so many people that I do not feel safe.

I am using a Mac. I have been a victim of ID theft in the past. I am thinking of buying a router and setting it up with the existing router, so I would connect to AP using my own password.

I am using a VPN as well, however, when I run Lanscan, I can see my actual IP address and other devices connected to Network. (I do not see anything on `ipleak.net`). My thought is that my VPN will encrypt all information and connect to AP, and AP shall connect to the router.

I have been a victim in the past and do not want to be complacent. Also, I want to stay away from commercial routers/access points. Please suggest if this is possible.

Comment: most routers get input from ethernet, not another wifi hotspot. you need something more akin to "internet connection sharing". if you have a 2nd computer with 2 wifi cards, that's the cheapest and maybe easiest way of adding your own router+hotspot to an existing wifi. your assumptions about security all seem reasonable.

Comment: The Wi-Fi connection between your AP and the router (if this is what you have in mind) would most probably be as (in)secure as Wi-Fi connection between your Mac and the router, no matter how fancy the Mac-AP connection is. Connecting your own AP to the router with a *cable* may improve your security and in this case your plan does make sense.